# How to do onChange with React Numeric Input

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use a spinbox in my code but whenever I try changing the values using onChange, the app crashes.
I also tried using onValueChange but it's getting ignored and I don't know what the problem is:

item.js

```
import NumericInput from "react-numeric-input";
import { Row, Col, ListGroup } from "react-bootstrap";

function ItemScreen() {
 
  const [qty, setQty] = useState(1);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2 className="text-center mb-3">Order</h2>
      <hr></hr>
      <Row>
        <Col md={8}>
          <ListGroup variant="flush">
            <ListGroup.Item>
              <Row>
                  <Col>Apple</Col>
                <Col>
                  <NumericInput
                    min={1}
                    max={100}
                    onChange={(e) => setQty(e.target.value)}
                    value={qty}
                  />
                </Col>
                <Col>
                  500 x {qty} = {qty * 500}
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </ListGroup.Item>
          </ListGroup>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ItemScreen;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `NumericInput` component event just return the numeric value so you can this I guess :

```
<NumericInput
   min={1}
   max={100}
   onChange={(value) => setQty(value)}
   />
```

Answer (score 1):

The value will always be of type string.

So you need to cast it as a number.

```
onChange={(e) => setQty(Number(e.target.value))}
```

Comment: It's still crashing with the error " Cannot read property 'value' of undefined "